# What's the best solution for huge amount of data,fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm currently using MYSQL,

and it becomes the bottle neck of the whole system

Answer (score 2):

Try Lucene indexing: lucene.apache.org. There is also a very good implementation in PHP as a part of Zend Framework.

Comment: How much out performant is it compared with nutch?I've used nutch,and it sometimes is not that fast neither.

Comment: Lucene-based systems need a lot of tuning to become performant. If you get it right, though, they're extremely quick.

Comment: I've read much reference about nutch,but rarely on tuning,could you give a link?

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (not to be confused with the Solar Framework for PHP).  It is based on Lucene and designed to scale, if that is one of your concerns.

Other Solr-related links you might find helpful:

- [Brief write-up at Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solr)
- [Solr Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html)
- [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/)